# what is best way to migrate sharepoint 2010 to a new server, in new office, and run concurrently with existing?

Tags: migration

We have two offices seperated by 2,000 miles. We use a MPLS to connect offices. I have Sharepoint installed in Office A. Office B complains too slow. I want to install Sharepoint on a server in Office B. I would assume that adding a new Web Front End Server wouldn't work as the server would still be connecting to Office A? Install Sahrepoint on new server, restore backup?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I haven't setup a farm in this manner, however check out this article from MS, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg441255.aspx. This should help you on your way.

Comment: a more detailed breakdown of that is available here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc560988.aspx#Enterprise